# Iterator as a separate class outside of the class of a linked list in C++

Tags: c++, class, templates, linked-list, iterator

I'm trying to work on an assignment where the professor has requested that the iterator for a Linked List has to be a separate header file.

However, all implementations I've seen of Iterators I've seen have the definition of the class inside of the bag/list class. So I have no idea how to create  an iterator within the bag like

```
dlist<int>::iterator it1
```

without defining it inside the list.

For  reference, here are my list, node, and iterator classes as is:

### dnode.h

```
template <class T>
class dnode{
    public:
        dnode(){
            linknext = NULL;
            prevlink = NULL;
        }

        void set_data(T item){data_value = item;}

        void set_next(dnode<T> *link){linknext = link;}

        void set_prev(dnode<T> *link){prevlink = link;}

        T data()const{return data_value;}

        dnode *next(){return linknext;}
        dnode *prev(){return prevlink;}

    private:

        dnode *linknext;

        dnode *prevlink;

        T data_value;
};
```

### dlist.h

```
#include "dnode.h"
#include "iterator.h"

template <class T>
class dlist{
    public:
        dlist(){head = tail = NULL;}

        void rear_insert(T data);

        void front_insert(T data);

        void front_remove();

        void rear_remove();

        void reverse_show();

        void show();

        iterator<T> begin(){return iterator<T>(head);}

        iterator<T> end(){return iterator<T>(tail);}

        iterator<T> r_begin(){return iterator<T>(tail);}

        iterator<T> r_end(){return iterator<T>(head);}

        void insert_after(iterator<T>& current,T item){
            dnode<T>* tmp;
            tmp = new dnode<T>;
            current.get_dnode()->next()->set_prev(tmp);
            tmp->set_data(item);
            tmp->set_next(current.get_dnode()->next());
            tmp->set_prev(current.get_dnode());
            current.get_dnode()->set_next(tmp);
        }

        void insert_before(iterator<T>& current,T item){
            dnode<T>* tmp;
            tmp = new dnode<T>;
            current.get_dnode()->prev()->set_next(tmp);
             tmp->set_data(item);
            tmp->set_next(current.get_dnode());
            tmp->set_prev(current.get_dnode()->prev());
            current.get_dnode()->set_prev(tmp);


        }
              friend class iterator<T>;
    private:
        dnode<T> *head;
        dnode<T> *tail;

};
```

### iterator.h

```
template <class T>
    class iterator
{
    public:    
        iterator(dnode<T> *first = NULL){current = first;}

    dnode<T>* get_dnode(){return current;}

    T& operator *()const{return current->data();}

    iterator& operator ++(){
        current = current->next();
        return *this;
    }

    iterator& operator ++(int){
        iterator original(current);
        current = current->next();
        return original;
    }

    iterator& operator --(){
        current = current->prev();
        return *this;
    }

    iterator& operator --(int){
        iterator original(current);
        current = current->prev();
        return original;
    }

    bool operator ==(const iterator something)const{ return current == something.current;}

    bool operator !=(const iterator something)const{ return current == something.current;}




private:
    dnode<T> *current;


};
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: You should look into friend methods/classes

Comment: something like having friend class List inside of the iterator class?

Comment: Close. To make it less coupled, have the Iterator class be a friend of the List class

Comment: Then create a method within the list class that returns an iterator for iterating over it

Comment: dlist.cpp is typo, no? Should be dlist.h? If not, you are probably in for a bit of trouble with the linker at some future point.

Comment: Yeah it's dlist.h don't know where cpp came from

Comment: A class chooses its friends. So if `Iterator` wants to mess with `List`'s internals, `List` must allow it by declaring itself a `friend` of `Iterator`. Example: Say you tell your friends your secrets. Parsnip Nose can't decide to be your friend and expect you to also tell him. You have to decide, "Parsnip Nose is cool." and tell him your secrets.

Comment: Ok, so I added friend class iterator<T> to my list function, however I'm still getting problems compiling, stating that iterator is not a member of dlist<int> when called by dlist<int>iterator it1;  Not sure how to implement the  method that returns an iterator for iterating it.

Comment: Update your code here to show how you are adding the Iterator as a friend

Comment: Updated the code to what I currently have

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but it may give you some ideas.  Have a look at how some of the MFC collection classes use a `POSITION` variable as an external iterator.  Here's an example: [CList Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxde0zae.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can *declare* the iterator and node types within the list class but *define* them elsewhere. The syntax you need is of the form as follows:

```
template <class T>
class list {
public:
    class iterator;
    struct node;

    node* head;

    iterator begin()
    {
        return head;
    }

    iterator end()
    {
        return head->prev;
    }
};

template <class T>
class list<T>::iterator {
    node* pos;
public:
    iterator(node* p) : pos (p) { }
    // ...
};

template <class T>
struct list<T>::node {
    node* next;
    node* prev;
    // ...
};

void f()
{
    list<int> l;
    list<int>::iterator i = l.begin();
    list<int>::node n;


}
```

When inside the definition of list, node or iterator you should no longer need the list:: prefix. Outside (which includes return types on functions defined outside those classes) you do need the list:: prefix.

In this form your include structure will be the reverse of what you have above where list.h does not need to include node.h or iterator.h but both of those files will include list.h. You might want to include node.h and iterator.h at the end of list.h so that users of your class can get all the definitions by including list.h.

Comment: Another thing is that they are separately compiled header files, so I can't have dlist<T>::iterator without the compiler getting angry at me for using a class that it  doesn't know exist